What does it mean to burn an SDR?
I am working on a project that requires a software defined radio. After some struggles, my advisor gave me another one and said "Don't burn this one this time." I asked him what that means and all he said was "you tell me."
I have tried looking around as to what that means with no success.
All I did was follow the instructions on the Nuand website to set up a bladeRF...

Did you damage the first one?  Did smoke come out?

Maybe he just threw the words out without really thinking, then when challenged said something cryptic so he didn't have to admit it. The world's full of 'em :-) Anyway, he's there to teach so get him to tell you straight.

What happened to the first one?

To "burn" a component in colloquial usage tends to mean to destroy it, especially inadvertently, especially by e.g. misconnecting power.

Where did the "diodes" come from?  OP didn't mention diodes in his question.

In one schematic, diodes at inputs are ESD0P8RFL or something like that. Are they "burned"? Did you tested the input with a "ohmmeter" low voltage and current?

Insert always a 20 dB attenuator at RF input ...  link diode https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-ESD0P8RFL-DS-v01_01-en.pdf?fileId=db3a30431441fb5d0114922f25950fd5

Figuring out what some person meant in some sort of context we know nothing about is not an electronics question.

The RX will have a maximum input level. I assume exceeding this significantly will damage the receiver. Haven't done it myself though. (yet).
